# Domain A use AJAX post though domain B then domain B set cookie self to login

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, cookies

Script at domain A fontend:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function($) { 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://domainB/setcookie.php",
            data:{
                'id': 'value'
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And http://domainB/setcookie.php file:

```php
<?php

 setcookie("u_id", $_POST["id"], 0, '/');

?>
```

And run http://domainB/index.php file:

```
The result of $_COOKIE["u_id"] is NULL EMPTY. I want $_COOKIE["u_id"] is "value".
```

Answer (score 0):

Your http://domainB/setcookie.php should be:

```
<?php
    setcookie('u_id', $_POST["id"], 0, '/', 'domainB');
```

When you pass domain name in 5th argument in `setcookie()`, it will set cookie for given domain. After that when you open `http://domainB/index.php`, cookie is available for that domain. Just replace your domain name in setcookie().